# Changing SensitivityLabel in Outlook 365 email with VBA

Tags: vba, azure, outlook

How can I access the methods of Office.SensitivityLabel in Outlook 365 to create and set a label for a new email?

Looking at the docs for this you would use

```vb
Dim myLabelInfo As Office.LabelInfo
Set myLabelInfo = ActiveDocument.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo()
```

to create a label object but there's no activedocument object in an Outlook mailitem, or in the Outlook application.

Object Browser view of Office.SensitivityLabel members
[image]

```vb
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With olMail
    .To = myRecipients
    .Subject = mySubject
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = myEmailBody
    '' Set Office.SensitivityLabel  // how do I set the label ?
    .Send
End With
```

Comment: Sensitivity Labels or any encryption propensities are not exposed in the Outlook Object Model.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I've found is using SendKeys which is prone to issues if the list of Labels changes.

```
Set Mail_Object = Outlook_App.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With Mail_Object
    
    '
    ' Set the Sensitivity Label - until details on how to access the property directly come to light
    '
    .Display
    
    SendKeys "%h" ' Alt H - gets the home menu
    SendKeys "AY" ' Sensitivity Label
    SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}" ' Change the number of {DOWN} to select a particular value from your list
    
    .Send ' Send it
    
End With
```